# jsonObject(with: data) succesfully reading valid json, but not returning valid json

Tags: ios, json, swift, validation

I am dealing with some issues with the following code:

```
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            let string1 = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Data could not be printed"
            print(string1)

            do {
                if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                    print("success")
                    print(jsonData as AnyObject)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

When I print out `string1` it is valid json and the line `print("success")` gets executed. However, when it reaches `print(jsonData as AnyObject)` the output is similar to json, but there are `=` in place of `:` and `()` in place of `[]`. In addition to this, some of the keys aren't even strings. It looks as follows:

```
  ( 
    { "build_path" = "<null>";
        city = "<null>";
        cm = "<null>";
        country = "<null>"; 
    }, {
        //similar to above
    }
 )
```

(the values are actually currently null)

I'm not really sure why this is happening so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how was your JSON object put together. With or without indents? as is, was it a single line string, or was it a "pretty printed" object?

Comment: break up your JSONSerialization step into two: one for jsonObject and another right after to cast it to your dictionary array. Depending on the result i might suggest you try the Decodable/Encodable approach. It works way better for dictionary arrays if you ask me.

Comment: That's just how `NSArray` is printed. Why are you expecting `jsonObject(with:)` to return "valid json"? It returns a Cocoa object depending on the top-level entity in the parsed JSON. In this case, it's an array; so you get an `NSArray` (which you then bridge to a Swift array, but then bridge back with `as AnyObject`).

Comment: https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375

Comment: @murphguy it was a single line string, I will take a look at Decodable/Encodable.

Comment: @Hamish Maybe "valid json" isn't the term to use. What you're saying makes a lot of sense, I think I can fix things up using that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `as AnyObject` in `print(jsonData as AnyObject)`. It will print in the format you are expecting.

Comment: `print(jsonData)` results in the same output

Answer (score 0):

I looked through some old code, so try with the following line for the JSONSerialization part:

```
if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
```

I got the correct result when just:

```
print(jsonData)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is trying to parse an array of dictionaries, not a single dictionary otherwise success wouldn’t get executed.

Comment: Btw using `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers` is pointless. And adding` JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions` is redundant. Btw You don't even need to pass the options parameter at all.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with OP's code. But it could be just shortened `if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {`

Comment: Ok, thanks. It was old code so I had not checked it really. All I knew was that it got what I thought I wanted. :)